# reference path of PowerShell version 4 or version 5 assembly

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-4.0

I want to host a PowerShell version5's assembly in my C# application, I have .NET Framework4.7 installed, 
 I only find the `System.management.automation.dll` from below paths:

1. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0\System.Management.Automation.dll`
2. `C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation`

Which one is the PowerShell V5's assembly?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `System.Management.Automation.PowerShell`, thats the assembly you will need. You can hit up [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation/) and grab this as well...

Comment: I can find `Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies`  in the NuGet, I am confused if I use NuGet to install the package I will have the `System.Management.Automation.dll`  from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Management.Automation.dll` , will this dll auto download when my exe run on another computer? @Çöđěxěŕ

Comment: `will this dll auto download when my exe run on another computer`, no you include them ...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, Microsoft says     *If this is the case, you should work to migrate your application to .NET 4.6+ (aka CLR4) using reference assemblies from Windows PowerShell 3.0 or later. That way, you’ll be using the latest version of the Windows PowerShell assemblies available on the box.*                            So if I use Nuget to include the powershell5's assembly , does it means that I do no need to use NET4.6?

Comment: That package requires >= 4.5, look at the dependencies... So no, you shouldn't have to use 4.6

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ actually I do not know the difference between adding reference and add a package by Nuget, and how I include the dll to exe?

Comment: If I only use the `RunspaceConfiguration.Create()` `RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()` `runSpace.CreatePipeline()` `pipeLine.Invoke()` method in my code, is there some deprecated method or parameters that I need to change when I update my assembly from Powershell2 to PowerShell5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to reference the installed version of Powershell on your host, you'd add a reference to `System.Management.Automation.Powershell` to your project. The article [Windows Powershell Host Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/hosting/windows-powershell-host-quickstart) gives you the gritty details.

Comment: Thank you, I have already completed the code, I just want to update the assembly from Powershell2 to Powershell5 @Adam

Comment: You're probably better off then working through the NuGet path then. As far as the two assemblies you referenced, I'd think one was 32-bit the other 64-bit. You'd included the one that matched your solution's processor architecture.